# VBA On.Time() Background Check in Combination with regular Usage

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I am currently experiencing an Issue with the On.Time()  Command.

The Ontime offsetvalue is set to 00:00:10 checking if Files are open. (Sort of a realtime checker).

```
Sub MacroAutoRun1()

Dim RunTime1 As Date
RunTime1 = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
Application.OnTime RunTime1, "MacroAutoRun1"

If IsFileOpen("H:\Operations_Front_Office\Organisation Helpdesk & Renseignement\Test\1\Statistik.xlsm") Then
    Interface.Interface_Statistik_Open_Val.Caption = "File in use"
Else
    Interface.Interface_Statistik_Open_Val.Caption = "File currently not used"
End If

If IsFileOpen("H:\Operations_Front_Office\Organisation Helpdesk & Renseignement\Test\1\Timesheet.xlsm") Then
    Interface.Interface_Timesheet_Open_Val.Caption = "File in use"
Else
    Interface.Interface_Timesheet_Open_Val.Caption = "File currently not used"
End If

If IsFileOpen("H:\Operations_Front_Office\Organisation Helpdesk & Renseignement\Test\1\Datasheet_Roulement_Final_Original.xlsm") Then
    Interface.Interface_Roulement_Open_Val.Caption = "File in use"
Else
    Interface.Interface_Roulement_Open_Val.Caption = "File currently not used"
End If
```

IsFileOpen is a created function as per below:

```
Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim iFilenum As Long
    Dim iErr As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    iFilenum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
    Close iFilenum
    iErr = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case iErr
    Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True
    Case Else: Error iErr
    End Select
End Function
```

My Problem now is that while doing the check it seems other Procedures are not able to be completed such as:

```
If DateDfrHDSKMALADIE = 0 Then
            Set FoundHDSKMaladie = Sheets("Congé + Maladie").Columns(1).Find(What:=Maladie1HDSKtxt, After:=Sheets("Congé + Maladie").Cells(1, 1))
            X = FoundHDSKMaladie.Row
            Y = FoundHDSKMaladie.Column + HDSKMALADIENumb
        Sheets("Congé + Maladie").Cells(X, Y) = "M"
```

Then the FoundHDSKMaladie returns "Nothing" and it seems to me that the Find Method is not even applied.

Have you heard of such an issue? I would like to keep the search open in the Background (peferably), if that would not work I will then just revert to stopping the Timer when the Page is left and reactivate it when the User returns to the page.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the method you are using are interuppting the other procedures, but I have used a similar things in the past using a workbook exists function. As the files that you are checking appear to be workbooks I'd suggest checking if using this function rather than the IsFileOpen function solves the issue. I beleive I saw this method in a excel/vba dummies book.

The string for the function would be "Statistik.xlsm" for example.

```
Function WorkbookExists(ByVal BookToCheck As String) As Boolean


Dim Path As String

On Error GoTo Find_Err
Path = Workbooks(BookToCheck).Saved
On Error GoTo 0
WorkbookExists = True
Exit Function

Find_Err:

WorkbookExists = False
End Function
```